PyGame Jump inconsistency
i'm new to pygame and i'm trying to implement a jump function for the first time , i'm using the code here below but many time i press spacebar the jump has a different height, i really don't understand where this comes from .I believe something related with velocity_y.
Someone is able to understand the issue? Or the approach is totally mistaken?
Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks a lot
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, groups, collision_sprites):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(join("Images", "player", "0.png")).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_frect(center=(100, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2))
        self.hitbox_rect = self.rect.inflate(0, 0)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.collision_sprites = collision_sprites

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2()
        self.speed = 500
        self.gravity = 0.8  
        self.isJumping = False  
        self.jump_height = 200  
        self.velocity_y = 0  
        self.on_ground = False  

        self.frames = {"one": [], "two": []}
        self.load_images()
        self.state = "one" 
        self.frame_index = 0

    def load_images(self):
        self.frames = {"one": [], "two": []}

        for file_name in sorted(listdir(join("Images", "player")), key=lambda name: int(name.split(".")[0])):
            full_path = join("Images", "player", file_name)
            surf = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()

            self.frames["one"].append(surf)
            self.frames["two"] = self.frames["one"] 

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.direction.x = int(keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]) - int(keys[pygame.K_LEFT])
        keys2 = pygame.key.get_just_pressed()

        if keys2[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.on_ground:
            self.isJumping = True
            self.velocity_y = -self.jump_height  
            self.on_ground = False  

    def move(self, dt):
        
        self.hitbox_rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed * dt
        self.collision("horizontal")  

        
        if not self.on_ground:
            self.velocity_y += self.gravity  

        
        self.hitbox_rect.y += self.velocity_y * dt
        self.collision("vertical")  

        
        if self.hitbox_rect.bottom >= WINDOW_HEIGHT: 
            self.hitbox_rect.bottom = WINDOW_HEIGHT
            self.on_ground = True  
            self.velocity_y = 0  

        self.rect.center = self.hitbox_rect.center

    def collision(self, direction):
        for sprite in self.collision_sprites:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(self.hitbox_rect):
                if direction == "horizontal":
                    if self.direction.x > 0:
                        self.hitbox_rect.right = sprite.rect.left
                    if self.direction.x < 0:
                        self.hitbox_rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                elif direction == "vertical":
                    if self.velocity_y < 0:  
                        self.hitbox_rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
                        self.velocity_y = 0  
                    elif self.velocity_y > 0:  
                        self.hitbox_rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
                        self.velocity_y = 0  
                        self.on_ground = True  

    def animate(self, dt):
        if self.direction.x != 0:
            self.state = "one" if self.direction.x > 0 else "two"

        
        if len(self.frames[self.state]) > 0:  

            if self.direction:  
                self.frame_index += 5 * dt
                if self.frame_index >= len(self.frames[self.state]):  
                    self.frame_index = 0

                
                self.image = self.frames[self.state][int(self.frame_index)]

        
        self.image = self.frames[self.state][int(self.frame_index)]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)  

    def update(self, dt):
        self.input()
        self.move(dt)
        self.animate(dt)

I tries to change gravity speed, jump height and vertical collision detection but nothing seems to work
